# Generate Numpy array of even integers that sum to a value

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a numpy solution that would allow you to initialize an array based on the following conditions?

1. Number of elements in axis 1. (In the example below you have 4 places in each element of the array)
2. Sum of values. (All elements sum to 8)
3. Step size. (Using increments of 2)

Essentially this shows all the combinations of 4 values you can add to achieve the wanted sum (8) at a step size of 2.

My experiments fail when I set the axis 1 dimension to over 6 and the sum to over 100.
There has to be a better way to do this than what I've been trying.

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 8],
       [0, 0, 2, 6],
       [0, 0, 4, 4],
       [0, 0, 6, 2],
       [0, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 6],
       [0, 2, 2, 4],
       [0, 2, 4, 2],
       [0, 2, 6, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 4],
       [0, 4, 2, 2],
       [0, 4, 4, 0],
       [0, 6, 0, 2],
       [0, 6, 2, 0],
       [0, 8, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 6],
       [2, 0, 2, 4],
       [2, 0, 4, 2],
       [2, 0, 6, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 4],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 4, 0],
       [2, 4, 0, 2],
       [2, 4, 2, 0],
       [2, 6, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 4],
       [4, 0, 2, 2],
       [4, 0, 4, 0],
       [4, 2, 0, 2],
       [4, 2, 2, 0],
       [4, 4, 0, 0],
       [6, 0, 0, 2],
       [6, 0, 2, 0],
       [6, 2, 0, 0],
       [8, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I doubt numpy has a function already implemented to solve any possible problem you may throw at it. It has lots of commonly used basic functions that you can assemble together into a program though...

Comment: What is "**My experiments**"? Could you add the code to your post? Maybe others can improve or extend your experimental code.

Comment: @Kdog What do you want to do with this array at the end ? The number of combinations will become very big that's why your code is probably crashing. If you intend to loop over it, you can probably create an iterator that will give you the `next` value at each iteration.

Comment: @bousof Yes, I was going to iterate over it and I agree that you want to keep the array from being stored in memory. Its just the way I'm generating the numbers using itertools is inefficient. I didn't post the code because it would focus peoples attention on one inefficient way of generating this array.

Comment: @Kdog Exactly. Not sure however that posting your itertools solution might have been a bad thing but the problem is clear so it's the most important thing. I tried to make an iterator for you please do not hesitate if you have questions or feedbacks.

Comment: @bousof Your answer is very impressive. This is the first time I'm dealing with a class. Please let me play with the solution and possibly check back with minor questions. Thank you!

Comment: @Kdog Thank you! Maybe you should read first about Object Oriented Programming using Python and also about Python's magic methods. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small code that will enable you to loop over the desired combinations. It takes 3 parameter:

- `itsize`: Number of elements.
- `itsum`: Sum of values.
- `itstep`: Step size.

It may be necessary to optimize it if the computations you do in the FOR loop are light. I loop over more combinations than necessary (all the `i,j,k,l` that take values in `0,itstep,2*itstep,...,itsum`) and keep only those verifying the condition that all sum up to `itsum`. The big size array is not computed and the rows are computed on-the-fly when iterating so you will not have the memory troubles:

```
class Combinations:
  def __init__(self, itsize, itsum, itstep):
    assert(itsum % itstep==0) # Sum is a multiple of step
    assert(itsum >= itstep) # Sum bigger or equal than step
    assert(itsize > 0) # Number of elements >0
    self.itsize = itsize # Number of elements
    self.itsum = itsum # Sum parameter
    self.itstep = itstep # Step parameter
    self.cvalue = None # Value of the iterator
  def __iter__(self):
    self.itvalue = None
    return self
  def __next__(self):
    if self.itvalue is None: # Initialization of the iterator
      self.itvalue = [0]*(self.itsize)
    elif self.itvalue[0] == self.itsum: # We reached all combinations the iterator is restarted
      self.itvalue = None
      return None
    while True: # Find the next iterator value
      for i in range(self.itsize-1,-1,-1):
        if self.itvalue[i]<self.itsum:
          self.itvalue[i] += self.itstep
          break
        else:
          self.itvalue[i] = 0
      if sum(self.itvalue) == self.itsum:
        break
    return self.itvalue # Return iterator value

myiter = iter(Combinations(4,8,2))

for val in myiter:
  if val is None:
    break
  print(val)
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
[0, 0, 0, 8]
[0, 0, 2, 6]
[0, 0, 4, 4]
[0, 0, 6, 2]
[0, 0, 8, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 6]
[0, 2, 2, 4]
[0, 2, 4, 2]
[0, 2, 6, 0]
[0, 4, 0, 4]
[0, 4, 2, 2]
[0, 4, 4, 0]
[0, 6, 0, 2]
[0, 6, 2, 0]
[0, 8, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 6]
[2, 0, 2, 4]
[2, 0, 4, 2]
[2, 0, 6, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 4]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 4, 0]
[2, 4, 0, 2]
[2, 4, 2, 0]
[2, 6, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 4]
[4, 0, 2, 2]
[4, 0, 4, 0]
[4, 2, 0, 2]
[4, 2, 2, 0]
[4, 4, 0, 0]
[6, 0, 0, 2]
[6, 0, 2, 0]
[6, 2, 0, 0]
[8, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out and also found that it slowed down significantly at that size. I think part of the problem is that the output array gets pretty large at that point. I'm not 100% sure my code is right, but the plot shows how the array size grows with condition 2 (sum of values in each row). I didn't do 100, but it looks like it would be about 4,000,000 rows

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvFKJ.png)